# Phonegap - configuring the config.xml file to enable the camera

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to create an app that makes use of the camera on the device.  When I run the app on my Android phone, I can get it to work no problem.  However, when I package it using the Phonegap builder, I can't seem to get the camera to open.

My guess is it's a problem with the config.xml file.  This is what mine looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <widget xmlns       = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
      xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
      id      = "com.test.testApp"
      version     = "1.0.0">

   <name>Test App</name>

   <description>
       Test Description
   </description>

   <author href="http://mysite.com"
       email="geoff@email.com">
       Geoff Baum
   </author>

   <gap:platforms>
       <gap:platform name="android" minVersion="2.1" />
       <gap:platform name="webos" />
       <gap:platform name="symbian.wrt" />
       <gap:platform name="blackberry" project="widgets"/>
   </gap:platforms>

  <icon src="icon.png" gap:role="default" />

   <!--<gap:splash src="weirdo.png" />-->

   <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
   <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
   <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
   <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
   <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
   <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
   <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>

   <!--<preference name="orientation" value="default" />-->
   <!--<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" /> -->
 </widget>
```

Does that look correct?  I have this file at the root level of the folder I am packaging and sending to Phonegap.  Is this the proper approach?  I am not sure what else I can do.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

---

UPDATE:
So I tried including the Android specific JS file cordova-1.7.0.js and everything worked.  So it looks like the Phonegap build is not adding the necessary files.  Does anyone know anything about that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution lay in the include files.  I was still including the phonegap.js file, and it was breaking the build process. I removed the various references to that file and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you have

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
```

twice?